# changing IP on sql server linked server

Tags: sql-server

I have a remote linked server that got moved to a different IP address.
After dropping the server with `sp_dropserver` and add it with new URL with `sp_addlinkedservers`, will I have to add everything back again (username, password, etc.)? 
Does `sp_dropserver` destroy the associated data ? Or that data is linked to the ID and kept? The server and respective SW is the same, only IP changes.

Comment: Add an entry to the local SQL Server's [hosts file](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=Windows+hosts+file&atb=v61-7__&ia=web), then point the linked server at that name, then you'll not have this problem in future.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, if you've dropped the linked server then you'll need to setup everything again from scratch.  You could script it out first, all you'll need to do then is change the IP address and password in the script and run it back in again.

Comment: Understood, thanks, David. So, there is always the need to know remote password.

Comment: Afraid so.  When you script out the linked server, SQL Server will always blank out the password in the script for security reasons.

Comment: You can obtain the password for linked server logins by decrypting them: https://blog.netspi.com/decrypting-mssql-database-link-server-passwords/